# Arabic character not working in DOMPDF

Tags: php, character-encoding, pdf-generation, dompdf

I have an issue with Arabic character when used in DOMPDF... I tried everything, but nothing is working...

My DOMPDF version is the last. I tried to install the font and set the charest to UTF-8 and [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256), but it is still not working...

Here's the code for the HTML page:

```
<?php require("login3.php"); ?>
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST)) {
        // Used for later to determine result
        $success = $error = false;

        // Object syntax looks better and is easier to use than arrays to me
        $post = new stdClass;

        // Usually there would be much more validation and filtering, but this
        // will work for now.
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $val)
            $post->$key = trim(strip_tags($_POST[$key]));

        // Check for blank fields
        if (empty($post->itemCode) OR
            empty($post->itemDesc) OR
            empty($post->itemQty) OR
            empty($post->itemPrice) OR
            empty($post->itemAgent))

            $error = true;
        else {
            // Get this directory, to include other files from
            $dir = dirname(__FILE__);

            // Get the contents of the pdf into a variable for later
            ob_start();
            require_once($dir . '/pdf.php');
            $pdf_html = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            // Load the dompdf files
            require_once($dir . '/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

            $dompdf = new DOMPDF(); // Create new instance of dompdf
            $dompdf->load_html($pdf_html, "UTF-8");  // Load the html
            $dompdf->render();  // Parse the html, convert to PDF
            $pdf_content = $dompdf->output(); // Put contents of pdf into variable for later

            // Get the contents of the HTML email into a variable for later
            ob_start();
            require_once($dir . '/html.php');
            $html_message = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();

            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Amman');
            $tym = date('m-d-Y : hi a');
            $filename = ' Order ' . $tym;
            $dompdf->load_html($_SESSION['prints']['table']);

            $dompdf->stream( $_SESSION["username"] . $filename . ".pdf"); // Streams the PDF to the client. Will open a download dialog by default

            // Load the SwiftMailer files
            require_once($dir . '/swift/swift_required.php');

            $mailer = new Swift_Mailer(new Swift_MailTransport()); // Create new instance of SwiftMailer

            $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                           ->setSubject('New Order') // Message subject
                           ->setTo(array('hussammoz@aol.com', 'hussammoz@GMAIL.com' => 'Orange Pharmacy Store')) // Array of people to send to
                           ->setFrom(array('no-reply@net.tutsplus.com' => 'Orange Pharmacy Order System')) // From:
                           ->setBody($html_message, 'text/html') // Attach that HTML message from earlier
                           ->attach(Swift_Attachment::newInstance($pdf_content,  $_SESSION["username"] . $filename . ".pdf", 'application/pdf')); // Attach the generated PDF from earlier

            // Send the email, and show user message
            if ($mailer->send($message))
                $success = true;
            else
                $error = true;
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <link href="favicon.ico" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <title>Orange Pharmacy Order System</title>

        <style type="text/css" title="currentStyle">
            @import "css/layout-styles.css";
            @import "css/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.css";

            {
                font-family: arabic, Arabic, Serif;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="includes/jquery.ticker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="includes/site.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>

        <!-- jQuery libraries-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/atooltip.jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kwicks-1.5.1.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

        <!-- Our jQuery script to make everything work -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jq-ac-script.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background="images/bg.jpg";>
        <div id="cont">
           <div style="position:absolute; top: 10px; left: 25px;">
           <a href="index.php" class="normaltip" style="text-decoration:none" title="Home"> <img src="images/home.png"height="48" width="48"></a></div>
           <div style="position:absolute; top: 60px; left: 25px;">
           <a href="order.php" class="normaltip" style="text-decoration:none" title="New  Order"><img src="images/system-software-update.png"height="48" width="48"></a></div>

        <div id="container">

        <h2 align="center"><img src="images/418694_259331167468533_385322251_n.jpg"></h1>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class="title-large">
            <div class="theme"></div>
        <p>
        <h4 align="left"><b>Branch: <FONT COLOR="white"><?php echo($_SESSION["username"]); ? ></b></h4>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function GetClock(){
                d = new Date();
                nday   = d.getDay();
                nmonth = d.getMonth();
                ndate  = d.getDate();
                nyear  = d.getYear();
                nhour  = d.getHours();
                nmin   = d.getMinutes();
                nsec   = d.getSeconds();

                if (nyear<1000)
                    nyear=nyear+1900;

                if (nhour ==  0) {
                    ap = " AM";nhour = 12;
                }
                else if(nhour <= 11) {ap = " AM";}
                else if(nhour == 12) {ap = " PM";}
                else if(nhour >= 13) {ap = " PM";nhour -= 12;}

                if(nmin <= 9) {nmin = "0" +nmin;}
                if(nsec <= 9) {nsec = "0" +nsec;}

                document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML =
                    "" + (nmonth+1) + "/" + ndate + "/" + nyear + "  " +
                    nhour + ":" + nmin + ":" + nsec + ap + "";
                setTimeout("GetClock()", 1000);
            }
            window.onload = GetClock;
        </script>

        <div id="clockbox"></div></font></div>
        <?php if ($success) { ?>
            <div class="message success">
                <h4>Order Successfully Sent to Store </h4>
            </div>
        <?php } elseif ($error) { ?>
            <div class="message error">
                <h4>Sorry, an error occurred. Try again!</h4>
            </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="content inpad">

            <div id="messageBox" style="margin-left:15px; padding-left:20px;  padding-bottom:5px; border:1px #ccc solid; display:none;"></div>

            <form method="post" action="#" id="itemsForm">
                <h1 align="center"><font color="black"><b>Branch Order Form</b> </font></h1><br><br>
                <select name="Priority" size="1">
                    <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
                    <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="Urgent">Urgent</option>
                </select>
                <table id="itemsTable" class="general-table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Item Code</th>
                            <th>Item Description</th>
                            <th>Item Qty</th>
                            <th>Item Price</th>
                            <th>Item Agent</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr class="item-row">
                            <td></td>
                            <td><input name="itemCode[]" value=""  class="tInput" id="itemCode" readonly="readonly" /> </td>
                            <td><input name="itemDesc[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemDesc"  tabindex="1"/></td>
                            <td><input name="itemQty[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemQty" tabindex="2"/></td>
                            <td><input name="itemPrice[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemPrice" readonly="readonly" /> </td>
                            <td><input name="itemAgent[]" value="" class="tInput" id="itemAgent" readonly="readonly" /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <a href="#" id="addRow" class="button-clean large"><span> <img src="images/icon-plus.png" alt="Add" title="Add Row" /> Add Item</span> </a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="SEND TO THE STORE">
            </form>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="container">
            <link href="styles/ticker-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

            <h1></h1>

            <ul id="js-news" class="js-hidden">

                <li class="news-item">WELCOME&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo($_SESSION["username"]); ?>&nbspBranch Team:)</li>
                <li class="news-item"><a href="newItem.php"target="_blank">LIST OF EXPIRY OF 03/2013 </a></li>
                <li class="news-item">&#1575;&#1604;&#1578;&#1610; &#1578;&#1606;&#1578;&#1607;&#1610; &#1576;&#1578;&#1575;&#1585;&#1610;&#1582; 06/2013 avene &#1575;&#1604;&#1585;&#1580;&#1575;&#1569; &#1587;&#1581;&#1576; &#1580;&#1605;&#1610;&#1593; &#1571;&#1589;&#1606;&#1575;&#1601; </li>
                <li class="news-item">REMEMBER THAT URGENT ORDERS MUST BE BEFORE 10 A.M AND  AFTER THAT ONLY DAILY ORDER</li>
                <li class="news-item">URGENT ORDER IS THAT WHICH CONTAIN ITEMS YOU DON'T   HAVE IN BRANCH OR CUSTOMER REQUEST!</li>
                <li class="news-item"><FONT COLOR="RED">NEW ITEM<a href="newdrug.php">&nbsp&nbspProspan Sachet</a></FONT>is available in store now... ORDER IT :)</li>
                <li class="news-item">Further updates to jQuery News Ticker are coming soon!</li>
            </ul>

            <noscript>
                <h2>Latest News</h2>
                <ul id="no-js-news">
                    <li class="news-item">jQuery News Ticker now has support for multiple tickers per page!</li>
                    <li class="news-item">jQuery News Ticker now has support right-to-left languages!</li>
                    <li class="news-item">jQuery News Ticker now has support for loading content via an RSS feed!</li>
                    <li class="news-item">jQuery News Ticker now has an optional fade effect between items!</li>
                    <li class="news-item">New updates have been made to jQuery News Ticker! Check below for more details!</li>
                    <li class="news-item">jQuery News Ticker is now compatible with jQuery 1.3.2! See below for further details and for latest download.</li>
                    <li class="news-item">Further updates to jQuery News Ticker are coming soon, come back soon for more details.</li>
                </ul>
            </noscript>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the PDF-generating page code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <style type="text/css">
            HTML, BODY
            {
                font-family: Serif, arabic;
            }
        </style>
            <h1 align="center"><img src=http://orangepharmacy.hostzi.com/418694_259331167468533_385322251_n.jpg></h1>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3 align="center"><b>Items&nbsp;<?php echo($_POST["Priority"]); ?>&nbsp;Order <br>   Branch: <FONT COLOR="ORANGE"><?php echo($_SESSION["username"]); ?></h3>
        <h6>
            <table id="itemsTable" border="1" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Item Code</th>
                        <th>Item Description</th>
                        <th> Qty</th>
                        <th> Price</th>
                        <th> Agent</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        foreach  ($_POST["itemCode"] as $Key=> $itemCode) {
                            $itemDesc=$_POST["itemDesc"][$Key];
                            $itemPrice=$_POST["itemPrice"][$Key];
                            $itemQty=$_POST["itemQty"][$Key];
                            $itemAgent=$_POST["itemAgent"][$Key];
                            echo "<tr><td></td><td>" . $itemCode . "</td><td>" . $itemDesc .
                                 "</td><td>" . $itemQty . "  </td><td>" . $itemPrice .
                                 "</td><td>" . $itemAgent ."</td></tr>";
                        }
                    ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </h6>

        <script type="text/php">

            if (isset($pdf))
            {
                $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("serif");

                // If verdana isn't available, we'll use sans-serif.

                if (!isset($font)) {
                    Font_Metrics::get_font("serif");
                }

                $size = 6;
                $color = array(0,0,0);
                $text_height = Font_Metrics::get_font_height($font, $size);
                $w = $pdf->get_width();
                $h = $pdf->get_height();

                // ------------------ FOOTER ------------------------------------------

                 if ($PAGE_NUM > 0)
                 {
                     $footer = $pdf->open_object();
                     $y = $h - 3 * $text_height - 24;
                     $text = "Orange Pharmacy   Tel: 5536170 - Fax: 5536171"; //"Page {PAGE_NUM} of  {PAGE_COUNT}"
                     $width = Font_Metrics::get_text_width("Orange Pharmacy    Tel: 5536170 - Fax: 5536171", $font, $size);
                     $pdf->page_text($w / 2 - $width / 2, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color);

                     // Copyright line
                     $y += $text_height * 2;
                     $text = "Madina Monawara - University Street - Hussain - Dabouq - Jabal Amman -  Airport - Dahet Alrasheed - Jubaiha - Yasmeen - Zarqa";

                     // Center the text
                     $width = Font_Metrics::get_text_width($text, $font, $size);
                     $pdf->page_text($w / 2 - $width / 2, $y, $text, $font, $size, $color);

                     // Add a logo
                     $img_w = 0.5 * 72; // 0.5 inches, in points
                     $img_h = 0.5 * 72; // 0.5 inch, in points -- change these as required

                     //$pdf->image("", 0, $y, $img_w, $img_h);
                     $pdf->close_object();
                     $pdf->add_object($footer, "all");
                 }

                 // ------------------ FOOTER END ------------------------------------------
             }
        </script>

        <script type="text/php">
            if ( isset($pdf) ) {
                $font = Font_Metrics::get_font("serif", "bold");
                $pdf->page_text(36, 9, "Page: {PAGE_NUM} of {PAGE_COUNT}",
                                $font, 6, array(0,0,0));
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried everything for a month, but nothing works. How can I fix it?

Comment: Usually you need to install the arabic fonts on your server - did you do that already?

Comment: yes I did.. using the load_font.php but not worked..

Comment: Your font order is backward. Order of precedence is left to right. Serif is the generic font family and should be the last in the list. Your style should be `html,body { font-family: arabic, serif; }`.

Comment: TCPDF and mPDF support for RTL languages is much better, try to use one them, here is an example using TCPDF http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.phps

Comment: The first step could be to ensure the (generated) HTML is well-formed. For instance, use [the W3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15484547&charset=utf-8) (using the URL of your live (test) site). For instance, right now, there seems to be some hanging `</div>`s.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I was about to give up on DOMPDF until I put the following at the top of the html:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body { font-family: DejaVu Sans, sans-serif; }
</style>
```

Simple, but all the question marks appearing in place of arabic disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

for me I used the following

```
 $html=mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8',
              mb_detect_encoding($html, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
$mpdf->autoScriptToLang = true;
$mpdf->autoLangToFont = true;
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

I use this packege for **`Persian`**  and its work well:

```
    https://github.com/mccarlosen/laravel-mpdf
```